# Encrypt/Protect some data between angular4 and a Web API (like asp.net viewstate)

Tags: angular, encryption, asp.net-web-api2

I’ve a form that has the following input field (and other fields also):

```
<input name="txtWorkPlace" type="text" [disabled]="user.hasServiceData == 1" [required]="user.hasServiceData == 0" maxlength="100" [(ngModel)]="user.WorkPlace" id="txtWorkPlace" #txtWorkPlace="ngModel" >
```

What I need is when the form post the data to a web API, I need to check `user.hasServiceData` if it is 1 then set `user.WorkPlace` to its original value that was sent to the angular form.

I've to minimize the access to DataBase as possible for performance issues.

What is the best technique to protect `user.WorkPlace` from being modified at the client by illegal ways.

*A straight thinking is to encrypt data at server and save it at the client in a hidden field or in some object, and send it again to the server when the Angular form post the user data, **but I'm looking for a better technique, may be a solution from Angular or a third party library...etc***.

Edit 1: simplified the question.

Comment: Does the user either have the ability to modify all data or none? If it's all or none, you can just hide the submit button using an `*ngIf` as this will not render the submit button at all if the condition is not met

Comment: Not all the data, only a section of the data , and when the case is not allowing to modify, this data should be displayed to the user, while `*ngIf` will display or hide.

Comment: if the input should be disabled, why not just use a one-way bind and disable the input? if they user can edit the input, then use a two-way bind. If you wanted to be extra careful, you could keep the record on a private variable, and make sure the inputs haven't been updated before posting the submit

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, now the problem is how to change the binding mode conditionally, i can't duplicate the controls within `*ngIf` because in the real case I've about 10 controls, not only one.

Comment: Create a component that has two inputs, one with two-way binding, one with one-way binding. Pass the value into that component and a flag stating whether it's a two-way or one-way binding and do the ngIf inside the component

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this will duplicate the controls, and I reached to a good solution to change the binding mode based on flag, which is:  `<input ...  [ngModel]="user.WorkPlace" 
(input)="user.WorkPlace = user.hasServiceData == 1 ? user.WorkPlace : $event.target.value"
id="txtWorkPlace" #txtWorkPlace="ngModel" >`

Comment: Also I will take a copy of the objects in private field to reset it before user post changes (as you suggested). Thanks for your help, but this still only client side validation, I still need to double check at server side.

Comment: That's fine. You could always perform a get to fetch the original record and compare it on the server side before performing the save/update action.